# how to bind the dropdown list to a typed dataset in C#?

Tags: c#

I have added a dataset(xsd) to my web application and cofigured it to SQL database and wrote a select query and named it as Getdata(). if i open the xsd file it has Getdata() method in it under TableAdapters. Dataset(xsd) TableAdapter has Getdata() method to get the details.How to call this method of TableAdapter of xsd in C# and bind the data to dropdownlist.please suggest me the complete C# code to do this.

Comment: Get the DataTable. Bind the DataTable. What's "not working"?

Comment: You'd better put some your code here. It would help others to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
YourTableAdapter  yourTableAdapter = new YourTableAdapter();
YourTypedDataSetClass.YourTableDataTable yourTable = yourTableAdapter .GetData();
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "TextFieldInYourTable";
dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "ValueFieldInYourTable";
dropdownlist1.DataSource = yourTable;
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

Comment: He used typed datasets, not LINQ.

Comment: Linq could be used to query data from typed dataset and it makes it easy. Please read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399358.aspx

Comment: Of course he can use LINQ to DataSet, but there is no any `XxxDataContext` class to make use of. You should edit your answer. BTW, I'm not the one down voting your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with this code

```
TypedDataSet typedDataSet  = ....;
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = typedDataSet.YourTable.YourColumn1;
dropdownlist1.DataValueField = typedDataSet.YourTable.YourColumn2;
dropdownlist1.DataSource = typedDataSet;
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```